# Spree/Rails user password reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, spree

I'm trying to set user's (admin) password from Rails console:

```
bundle exec rails console
> Spree::User.first.email
=> "admin@mysite.com"
> Spree::User.first.encrypted_password
  Spree::User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "spree_users".* FROM "spree_users" LIMIT 1
=> "4ec556............................................."
>  Spree::User.first.password='spree123'
  Spree::User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "spree_users".* FROM "spree_users" LIMIT 1
=> "spree123"
>  Spree::User.first.password_confirmation='spree123'
  Spree::User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "spree_users".* FROM "spree_users" LIMIT 1
=> "spree123"
>  Spree::User.first.save!
  Spree::User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "spree_users".* FROM "spree_users" LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (1.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "spree_users"."id") FROM "spree_users" LEFT OUTER JOIN "spree_roles_users" ON "spree_roles_users"."user_id" = "spree_users"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "spree_roles" ON "spree_roles"."id" = "spree_roles_users"."role_id" WHERE "spree_roles"."name" = 'admin'
   (0.3ms)  COMMIT
=> true
> Spree::User.first.encrypted_password
  Spree::User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "spree_users".* FROM "spree_users" LIMIT 1
=> "1bc15d.............................................."
```

So far so good. It looks like the new password for the user has been changed and commited to the database. However when I try to log in later with a web client and using the new password, it fails with invalid identity/password message.
I even tried to update password with `Spree::User.first.reset_password!('spree123', 'spree123')` but sill cann't sign in.

Rails 3.2.12
Spree 1.3.2

Any idea what am I doing wrong ? How to properly set a new password ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

The problem is that every time you're doing `Spree::User.first` it's reloading the record from the database. This means you are setting the value on one instance of the record, reloading it, and then saving the reloaded model that hasn't actually changed. An easy way around this is to create a local instance variable containing the record and update that instead:

```
user = Spree::User.first
user.password='spree123'
user.password_confirmation='spree123'
user.save!
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately even assigning instance to a local variable did not helped. I had to create a new admin with *rake spree_auth:admin:create* and do changes with the web admin interface.

Answer (score 0):

```
Spree::User.first.update_attributes(password: 'password')
```